# Flip image using python

Tags: python

I tried to flip horizontally((about Y axis)) all the images in a specific folder using python
I want to keep the initial images and for the flipped ones I want to rename them as *_flip.jpg. I am stuck . How to do it?

Comment: take a look at PIL (http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/)

Answer (score 3):

You can loop through each image in the directory and use `flip` of OpenCV to flip it horizontally on based on what axis you want. You can then save the flipped file accordingly.

Look at the following snippet to get an idea.

```
import os
import cv2

directory = ''

for file in os.listdir(directory):
    img = cv2.imread(directory + file)
    horizontal_img = cv2.flip( img, 0 )

    #saving now
    cv2.imwrite(file + '_flip' + '.jpg', horizontal_img)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: thank you so  much ...but may be i could not write the directory in a proper way...i tried so many times ... but i could not find flipped image in my directory

the error is :

OSError: [WinError 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect: 'F:\\skin disease detection and classification\x0cliped image\\Eczema Hand\\'

can you help me please ?

Comment: Are you sure 'F:\\skin disease detection and classification\x0cliped image\\Eczema Hand\\' exist.? If yes try putting `/` rather than `\\`

Comment: actually my path is : "F:\skin disease detection and classification\fliped image\Eczema Hand" 

but when I used that path then the error is :
OSError: [WinError 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect: 'F:\\skin disease detection and classification\x0cliped image\\Eczema Hand\\'

Comment: set path like this "F://skin disease detection and classification//fliped image//Eczema Hand//" if it fails try "F:\\skin disease detection and classification\\fliped image\\Eczema Hand\\"

Comment: I have used both path ....but  nothing is worked  at all :( :(
code link : https://pastebin.com/z2inxAnL